# How to Programmatically enable the check box "Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation" in Service Account through API

Tags: google-api, service-accounts

I am able to create Service Account and Service Account key programmatically by using api's but I'm not able to Automatically enable this check box through any REST API, could anyone please let me know ways to enable it programmatically.

Thanks in Advance !!!!

Comment: Service accounts are used to access apis programmaticly it is not going to be able to check a checkbox on a website.   Which api are you trying to access maybe the api has the ability to set this value.

Comment: I have created this service account to monitor G Drive of all users under an Admin Account, I'm able to create Project, Service Account, Enable API's on Project and Generate Service Account key programmatically, but I'm not able to enable the check box in , i.e "Enable G Suite Domin-Wide Delegation" check box that is under service account, I want to do this also programmatically, is there any way in which I can do this.

Comment: I'm Using Service Account to Impersonate users under admin account to access their GDrive Data